# How to merge JSON objects in Redhift?

Tags: sql, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Let's say I have two rows

```
Account | usage | usage by user      | usage month
1       | 20    |  { "a":10, "b":10} | Jan
1       | 25    |  { "a": 15, "c":10}| Feb
```

I want to write a query to get the total usage as

```
1       | 45    | { "a" : 25, "b" :10, "c":10}
```

I can get the usage by using SUM and group by Account. But I'm not sure on how to merge the json objects in **Redshift**. Any pointers on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There is no native way to do this in Amazon Redshift. Also, I would **recommend that you do *NOT* do this in Redshift.**

JSON fields are difficult to interpret within Redshift. You would need to use a function like [JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT.html) to retrieve elements from JSON. It is quite inefficient and does not take advantage of the capabilities of Redshift to optimize queries.

If you are keeping such a field to hold **1-to-many value relationships**, it would be better to **create a separate *usage* table** that holds the usage information per account and user. Then, then join to that table in your queries. This is normal SQL — nothing specifically to do with Redshift.

For example, see: [Creating multiple tables and table relationships](https://launchschool.com/books/sql/read/table_relationships#onetomany)